# Sonata Admin - Unable to get sonata_type_collection working with modal

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

In my admin I have a OneToMany defined as it:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Module", mappedBy="sequence", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
 private $modules;
```

And the inversed side:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ModuleSequence", inversedBy="modules", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="LAZY")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="sequence_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $sequence;
```

In my admin class I defined the 'modules' field as it:

```
->add('modules', 'sonata_type_collection',array(
       'by_reference' => false
 ))
```

Finally in the ModuleSequence Entity here's the addModule method:

```
     /**
     * Add modules
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Module $module
     * @return ModuleSequence
     */
    public function addModule(\AppBundle\Entity\Module $module)
    {
        $module->setSequence($this);
        $this->modules[] = $module;

        return $this;
    }
```

I have the "add" button, I get the modal, I fill it and validate. The Ajax request is sent into the profiler but no new row appear.

The 'sequence_id' is not set in the database and I don't know why... Any idea please?

When I use the 'inline' & 'table' options, the id is well set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long discussion on Sonata Admin GitHub here:

https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/4236

Problem partially solved...

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and solved it with overriding the prePersist and preUpdate methods and then persist the associations.

```
public function prePersist($object)
{
    $this->persistBlocks($object);

    $content->mergeNewTranslations();
}

public function preUpdate($object)
{
    $this->prePersist($object);
}

private function persistModules($object)
{
    $em = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');

    foreach($object->getModules() as $module)
    {
        $module->setObject($object); // change Object to the name of your Entity!!
        $em->persist($module); 
    }
}
```